# Simplify Converting List<DateTime> to SortedSet<long>

Tags: c#

I am trying to simplify my solution below where I am trying to convert a `List<DateTime>` to `SortedSet<long>`. I am wondering if this is even possible?

```
List<DateTime> dateTimes = new List<DateTime>();
dateTimes.Add(...);    

// simplify the 5 lines below into 1 line
SortedSet<long> timestamps = new SortedSet<long>();
foreach(DateTime dateTime in dateTimes)
{
    timestamps.Add(convertDateTimeToTimestamp(dateTime));
}
```

I have been able to convert a `List<float>` to `List<double>` via:

```
List<float> average = new List<float>();
average.Add(...);
List<double> newAverage = average.Select(x => (double?)x).ToList();
```

I however was unable to find a `.ToSet()` or `.ToSortedSet()` method.

Comment: There is a `.ToHashSet()` method, but not a `.ToSortedSet()` method.

Comment: @John Ahh, thank you. Is there a reason why there would not be a `.ToSortedSet()`?

Comment: On looking more closely, it seems that `.ToHashSet()` doesn't exist in .NET Framework, but does in .NET Core and presumably .NET Standard. It seems like a new addition. Maybe they will add more in future.

Comment: @Jon: The reason why there is not a feature you want is always the same: **No one implemented that feature**. In order for you to use a feature, someone has to implement it. You didn't implement it, and no one else did either. **Why didn't you implement it?**

Comment: @EricLippert To be frank, I am surprised .NET went for `ToList()` instead of generic `ToCollection<T>() where T: ICollection<T>` method.

Comment: @Joker_vD: I don't understand your proposal; could you provide an implementation of such a method?

Comment: @EricLippert: I don't think it's a good idea, but I assume Joker is asking for something like this: `public static T ToCollection<T,U>(this IEnumerable<U> collection) where T: ICollection<U>, new() {T retval = new T();foreach(U item in collection){retval.Add(item);}return retval;}` .  I could not find any way to implement this that doesn't require the caller to specify type arguments explicitly.

Comment: @Brian: There is no way to write that method without providing the type arguments explicitly. C# does not allow *partial* inference of type arguments; you've got to infer all of them or supply all of them, nothing in between. Joker_vD, it looks like Brian implemented your desired method in a comment, so now you don't need to add it to the framework; you can just copy that five-line method.

Comment: @EricLippert Right. I am wrong, because I've went and look at the actual code I used in a project several years ago, and it has `ICollection<T> ToCollection<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Func<ICollection<T>> factory)` signature, plus a helper so you can write `Make.New<SortedSet<string>>` instead of `() => new Sorted<string>()` — indeed, there is no *partial* inference for typeargs. Basically, it's Java's `Stream.collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet<String>::new)`, but in Java you can write just `HashSet::new` (because of erasure, I think?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about using the constructor overload that takes `IEnumerable<T>`?:

```
timestamps = new SortedSet<long>(dateTimes.Select(convertDateTimeToTimestamp));
```

Or wrapping it up in an extension method:

```
namespace System.Linq
{
    public static class CustomLinqExtensions
    {
        public static SortedSet<TSource> ToSortedSet<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
        {
            if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
            return new SortedSet<TSource>(source);
        }

        public static SortedSet<TSource> ToSortedSet<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, IComparer<TSource> comparer)
        {
            if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
            return new SortedSet<TSource>(source, comparer);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can simply call `dateTimes.Select(convertDateTimeToTimestamp).ToSortedSet();`